# Query postgis table using R for dataframe of lon and lat

Tags: r, postgis

Is there any way to send a dataframe of longitude and latitude to a postgis connection from R. For e.g.
below code connects to a postgis database and gets the value from the underlying table for a given lon and lat.

```
library(RPostgres)
library(dplyr)

con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                 host = "xxx", 
                 dbname = "mytable",
                 port = 5432,
                 user = "xx",
                 password = "xx")

lon <- -70.60
lat <- 41.55

dat <- dbGetQuery(
              con, 
              paste0("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
                     WHERE 
                     ST_INTERSECTS(MYTABLE.GEOMETRY,ST_SETSRID(ST_MAKEPOINT(",lon",",lat,"),4326)))")
```

Comment: I don't have the GIS extension installed on my postgres, does this query not work for you? Or is the problem that you have more than one `lon`/`lat` pair and you're like to query across all of them?

Comment: BTW: you may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).

Comment: @r2evans yes I have more than one lon/lat pair in an R dataframe and I would like to query across all of them,

Comment: I would start with `WITH input_points AS (SELECT points FROM ... ) SELECT * FROM mytable ...`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344902/osm-postgresql-queries might be a helper.